# After downloading the file from url using urlsessiondownloadtask the file is not opening

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

When I try to download the file from the url the files gets downloaded and is stored in files folder. But when I try to open the file. The file appears to be corrupted and I am not able to open the pdf file.

I have tried all the possibilites using the following code mentioned. But none of them worked. Any solution thanks in advance.

```
static func downloadFileFromUrl(urlString:String, fileName:String,viewController : UIViewController) {

    // Create destination URL
    if let documentsUrl:URL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first{
        let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName)")
        //Create URL to the source file you want to download
        let fileURL = URL(string: urlString)
        let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
        let request = URLRequest(url:fileURL!)
        let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in
            if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
                // Success

                 try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destinationFileUrl)
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: destinationFileUrl)
                    do {
                        //Show UIActivityViewController to save the downloaded file
                        let contents  = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
                        for indexx in 0..<contents.count {
                            if contents[indexx].lastPathComponent == destinationFileUrl.lastPathComponent {
                                let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [contents[indexx]], applicationActivities: nil)
                                viewController.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (let err) {
                        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.makeToast(message: err.localizedDescription)
                    }
                } catch (let writeError) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.makeToast(message: "Error creating a file :- \(writeError.localizedDescription)")
                    })
                }
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.makeToast(message: "Error downloading the file")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Now the file after downloading is not opening. Is there any problem with code mentioned to download file from url

Comment: where you are adding extension to the file ?

Comment: @AshishGupta I am sending the file name as "filename.pdf"

Comment: Can't you just compare the downloaded file contents against the server version to see if you are downloading the file correctly.  Then you know if the issue is in your download code or not.

Comment: Why do you get the contents of the directory and check the file? You do have the URL.

Comment: @vadian getting the contents is not required you mean??

Comment: Yes, not at all. If copying the file fails you get an error otherwise `destinationFileUrl` is valid. And by the way never wrap strings in string interpolation (`documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(fileName)`)

Answer (score 0):

CompletionHandler of downloadTask Method is performed in Global (Background) Queue. You have to present your activityViewController in Main Queue.

Use the following code to present your activityViewController:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
   let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [contents[indexx]], applicationActivities: nil)
   viewController.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)    
})
```

instead of just

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [contents[indexx]], applicationActivities: nil)
viewController.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```